# Something like Spock's "@Unroll" for JUnit theories?

Tags: unit-testing, junit

I used Spock, and there is this brilliant `@Unroll` annotation, which makes all the runs of test method look like separate tests.

Is there something like that for JUnit `@Theory`? When `@Theory` test method is run multiple times (with different parameters), it still looks like one method run in the IDE. I'd like to see each run separately.

Comment: I think this is a valid question - is there an equivalent in JUnit for @Unroll. Why is this closed?

Comment: Hey, I'm not asking a recommendation for a book, tool, lib or any other resourse, do I? I just want to solve a problem and I'm asking how. Possible answer is "No", or "Yes, it's @JUnitUnroll". How can it be more specific?

Answer (score 2):

There is now a small JUnit tool tellingly called [spockito](http://spockito.tools4j.org) from [tools4j](http://tools4j.org) which offers a @TableSource annotation (for junit5, or @Unroll for junit4).

Note that for junit5 you can also use @ParameterizedTest with some @ArgumentsSource, e.g. with @CsvSource.

Disclosure: I am involved in tools4j and the spockito project.

Answer (score 1):

There is currently no way to do this, as of JUnit 4.12.

Answer (score 1):

[this github project](https://github.com/richard-melvin/junit-theory-suite) does this.

junit-theory-suite is a simple library that replaces the default JUnit theories runner with one that treats each individual combination of parameters as a distinct test case.